# Do logical operators (+, || etc) work with multiple documents (blobs) in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have configured my Azure Search for the Database as well as a Container in a Storage Account with Blobs.
The single word Search works fine across the data sources. And also, multiple word search with logical operators works fine in the context of a single Blob.
But, its not giving me desired result, as my Search needs to work in the context of collection of blobs.

I have a database object to which multiple documents are attached (stored as blob in different folders under a Container). My search (with multiple words and logical operators) needs to show the User the business object in case it hits the condition valid for multiple documents attached to the business object.

So, I have a business object "A" with documents "B", "C" and "D" attached, stored in the folder "E" under a Container (for which Indexer has been created in my Azure Search). Document B has word "king" and C has word "queen" in it. In this scenario, if I search "king + queen" then it doesn't give my any result. I would like to get "A" in my search result, as collectively, it satisfies the "king + queen" condition.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean operators in Azure Search queries work on individual document level. In your example, querying “king + queen” would search for documents that contain both “king” and “queen” – [read more here about simple query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/query-simple-syntax#boolean-operators-and-or-not).

If you have other identifying criteria for business object "A" (like a **name** or an **object-id** field), you can construct a query to capture that, and use a logical "OR" to list the keywords, e.g. – "*A + (king | queen)*" when using **queryType=simple** (which is the  default). You may also consider using the **queryType=full** mode for a more expressive query language where you could also express expected values of individual fields (like "*name:A*"). For further reading, see [Lucene query syntax in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, in my case, search would be executed by Users, on whom I have no control. My guess is, Users would go for more intuitive way of search, which to me looks like only "+" in between keywords. Is there any way to group a set of documents so that Indexers assumes them as one single document?

Comment: Unfortunately, indexers do not have a capability of merging multiple source documents to a single document. In your original example, since the query is not expected to reference the business-object\group, what is the expected result if multiple documents belonging to different groups contain the same keywords? For example,  document “B” contains “king”, document “C” contains “queen”, both logically belong to business object “A” (like in your example) but if document “Z” that is logically part of business object “X”, also contains “king”?

Comment: In that case, only the business object "A" should show up, as document "Z" doesn't satisfy "king + queen" criteria. Business object "X" should be shown only if "Z" also has "queen" or "X" has another document "W" with word "queen" in it.

Comment: I see. but without any property to connect documents that belong to the same business object, it would be generally not possible. In addition, in your example, business objects are not document themselves, but rather logic groups, so it seems you would have to model those as documents at indexing time or introduce a layer between the customer raw query and Azure Search, a layer tha would add the relevant id of the business object to the query and potentially also process the results (merge?) to produce the desiered business logic.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to achieve looks like a very standard business use case to me and Microsoft needs to come up with an easier way to manage this. I of course have a logical grouping of documents with ID of the business object stamped on documents as metadata, and have stored them separately in ID named folders separately.